# Extract an ID value from a string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

IN a JavaScript Event I only have access to a string in this format below...

```
var innerHTML = '<img src="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/7988569?v=3&amp;s=40"
class="item-image picker-item-thumb"><i id="2">Item 2</i>';
```

I need to extract the ID value from this part `<i id="2">` so I would have `2` in a variable.

Also none of the other HTML tags will ever have an ID besides the `<i>`

I'm not sure how to do this?

Comment: Parse the HTML to DOM elements, find the `i` element and access its `id` property.

Comment: Convert it to DOM elements by assigning it to the `innerHTML` of a `DocumentFragment`. Then use DOM methods to access the elements and attributes.

Comment: It's even easier if you use jQuery: `$("<div>", {html: innerHTML}).find("i").attr("id")`

Comment: Why is your HTML a String in the first place? It's just `Element.id` in JavaScript if you're working on the DOM.

Comment: @PHPglue I am extracting it from an Event that is fired from another library.  I need the ID but it only sends me a jQuery event with some HTML as strings

Comment: Sounds like a bad design.

Comment: @PHPglue not sure enough is known for those sort of assessments. Having html in strings is not uncommon

Comment: @Barmar that works great thanks

Comment: It makes more sense to have your Server code send JSON if using AJAX, if that's even what is going on here. Build your HTML code on the Client Side once you have received the sufficient JSON data.

Comment: @PHPglue I'm not doing anything but receiving it from a 3rd party script...If I was doing it, I wouldn't have to do all this trouble as I would simply send the ID in my JS Event

Comment: if you are using jQuery can use `$(innerHTML).filter('i')[0].id;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex capturing group.

If the id is always numeric, use:

```
/<i id="(\d+)"/.exec(innerHTML)[1]
```

Else, you can use

```
/<i id="([^"]+)"/.exec(innerHTML)[1]
```

Suggest to look at the comments for further information!

Comment: That would return `foo" bar="baz` for `<i id="foo" bar"baz" />`.

Comment: @FelixKling Well the question is specifically for the format `<i id="2">`, but yeah. Need to keep in mind.

Comment: @aarjithn 1. Fix `InnerHTML` to `innerHTML`.  Better use `/<i id="(\d+)"/.exec(innerHTML)[1]` quite fine for numerical ID

Comment: @aarjithn this is the issue Felix pointed out - http://jsbin.com/lodebu/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output - where `(\d+)` prevents it. Though worth noting that Error will be thrown using your examples if an Alpha character is used as ID.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I've put the list of characters possibly used for an ID :) This should fix the issue.

Comment: @aarjithn: Simpler would be `[^"]+` :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan AFAIK, spaces are not valid inside ID attribute in html. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @aarjithn well you're right. Must be the late hour.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do it:

```
(?<=i id=").+(?=")
```

As pointed by felix king you can try the following  as javascript doesn't support lookbehinds:

```
/i id="(.+)"/

var innerHTML = '<img src="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/7988569?v=3&amp;s=40"
class="item-image picker-item-thumb"><i id="2">Item 2</i>';
var arr = innerHTML.match(/i id="(.+)"/)[1];
alert(arr);
```

`arr` will have all the matches.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=i id=").+(?=")/: Invalid group(…)`.

Comment: @NishanthMatha `(.+)"` might fail if user adds another attribute to the `<i>` element - since `.+` will match any character > since the last occurrence of `"`. `(\S+)` is a somewhat  better solution

Comment: Now it's the same solution as aarjithn's with the same initial issues. Have a look at the comments on that answer.